# How to make Windows 10 recognize my monitors size properly?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have one 4K 32'' monitor, and two 24'' 1080p monitors.

Windows thinks the 24'' monitors fit right on top of the 32'' inches one, but in reality they don't and the "extended" desktop is all messed up because of that. See the image:

[image]

How to make windows understand that my secondary monitors are larger and have a lower ppi?

If not possible, are there any applications that could help with this?

Comment: Are monitors 3 and 4 on their correct resolutions (1920x1080)?

Comment: Yes they are. And since the monitor 2 is 4k, windows seems to think monitors 3 and 4 fit on its top... I can't seem to find a way to tell windows that monitors are 24'' and don't fit like that.

Comment: You still need an answer for this?